# I need to click on <A> tag having value clickMe

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to click on an element with the following HTML:

```
<td class=datagrid><a onclick='openWindow( "815");' href="#">clickMe</a></td>
```

Using selenium with InternetExplorerDriver

Or, click on another tag with below HTML:

```
<img border=0 src="images/graph_grid_total.gif">
```

Comment: <TD class=datagrid><A onclick='openWindow( "815");' href="#">clickMe</A></TD>

Comment: <IMG border=0 src="images/graph_grid_total.gif">

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='clickMe']").click()` to click an `a` tag with `value` set to `clickMe`.

To click the `<img>` tag, you can use `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='images/graph_grid_total.gif']").click()`